# Class Convert one name space to another asp.net entity framwork

Tags: asp.net, webforms

i have web forms application in asp.net with 3-tire architecture with Entity framework database first(.edmx) i want separate class library for entities i have created but when i am updating .admx file from database context.cs file loose name space newly created entity class library.
please give me alternative solution.